# Geocoder is too slow for searchview

Tags: android, performance, handler, geocoding, searchview

I've got the following code:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(); //global variable

searchAddress.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        List<Address> foundAddresses = gc.getFromLocationName(newText,10);
                        Log.e("res",foundAddresses.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0);
            
        return true;
    }
});
```

The issue is that there is always a way to large delay on the searchviewfield when I'm trying to change the locationname. It does not run smoothly like for. e.g. in google maps.
I tried using `AynchTask` but the result was much worse than using a `Handler`.

Is there a way to optimize my code much more for performance issue?
Right now it looks just too ugly cause when a character is entered there is always a 2 second delay before the character appears on the searchviewfield.

Comment: `Is there a way to optimize my code much more for performance issue?` well, not sure this has much to do with performance, if this is an api call and the api call takes 1-2 seconds to complete, then there isn't much you can do about that

Comment: @a_local_nobody i guess google takes another approach then? cause they deliver results much faster with the same api as far as i know

Comment: yeah, i'd guess implementations of this make use of lists of data which are already cached, wouldn't make sense to search for all locations starting with X over an api call as someone types, but would make more sense to get a large list of locations starting with X and then autocompleting based on what the user types. asking for library suggestions here is off-topic and people aren't recommended to give these out, but the Places api makes this type of operation quite simple, depending on what you need, perhaps it can help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see one big problem-  your code isn't really canceling any API calls.  Let's say the user type "the".  Let's say he types 5 keys per second.  So at time t=0, he types t.  at t=5ms or so, your onQueryTextChange will be called.  At time t=6ms or so, your onPostDelayed will run and make an API call.

Now the h comes in a t=200ms.  At 2=205 ms, you cancel all messages.  The problem is the message has already run.  So you cancel nothing.  Which means if he's typing a the rate of 5 keys per second, you're making 5 api calls per second.

The delay in your post delay should be large enough that its detecting actual delays in typing, and not firing per character.  Otherwise you just have a ton of API calls out.  Worse, you open yourself to race conditions if for some reason API call 2 returns before API call 1.  For a good number on delay, I'd use a typing trainer and see what your wpm is, and use that to figure out a reasonable delay of maybe 2x what your average time for a character is.  That's a good first pass at it.

Also, Google maps caches a significant amount of data locally.  It's unlikely they run all character by character matching back to the server.  At the very least they'd use cached local data for fast results and network for more detailed results.